# How to display custom building on mapbox-gl map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, vuejs3, mapbox-gl-js

I wan't to display my own buildings on map(as in example). They should be static - [my screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OtSS.jpg)

At screenshot you can see example with marker building(it moves on map move or zoom in/out)

My purpose - this [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3YOy.jpg)

I want to create map with isometric buildings, which can have different opacity

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/

Each of your building images should be added as a raster layer with the `coordinates` argument specifying the coordinate boundaries of the building:

```
map.addSource('building1', {
  'type': 'image',
  'url': 'building1.png',
  'coordinates': [
    [-80.425, 46.437],
    [-71.516, 46.437],
    [-71.516, 37.936],
    [-80.425, 37.936]
  ]
});
```

The images will automatically scale as you zoom in and out to maintain the correct coordinates.

Comment: My 2d building takes wrong form, image become stretched.

Comment: I have updated my help request